# "Let's see them aliens" grammar

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns, jokes

I know this was a joke on Facebook, the thing about storming Area 51. But, what catched my eyes is the "them".
Is this playing on word? Or, is this grammaticality sound? Or is this a joke because I, as non native speaker, don't get it.
Isn't it supposed to be:

> *Let's see them, the aliens*
> OR
> *Let's see the aliens*

I hope this question isn't off-topic but I really want to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Them** is a colloquial way of saying **those**, such as [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gold_in_them_thar_hills)

> There's gold in them thar hills.

and usually, what **them** refers to has already been mentioned. It's not just a synonym though, it might be a way to express mockery or disbelief in something rumoured:

> Let's see them aliens.

So in this case it is *loaded* and says rather more than "those".

Comment: I would not use "them" in that way until you get very confident and practised.

Comment: I would say demonstrative *them* is nowadays characteristic of dialect rather than register; speakers of standard Englishes only use it jocularly, or in imitation or mockery. A learner would be best to avoid it. But like so many things, this is a social convention, dating only from the 19th century. The Lord's Prayer in the earliest editions of the *Book of Common Prayer* reads *forgive us our trespasses, as we forgive them that trespass against us*.

Comment: @choster: that is different. _Them_ is normally a pronoun, and using it for pronoun _those_ is less common, but still standard. In the question, _them_ is used as a **determiner** (traditional grammars would have called it a demonstrative adjective) and that has never been standard as far as I know. .